# what are the zeroes of $\sqrt{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

well I need to know whether there are any zeroes of $\sqrt{z}$? so far I guess $0$ is a singular point of  the function as it is not analytic at $z=0$, so It has no zeroes am I right? Is it an isolated singularity? please help.

Comment: I wonder, does $(|z| = |w| \implies |f(z)| = |f(w)|) \implies $f is analytic? $\sqrt z$ falls under this case.

Comment: @trinithis That seems sort of unrelated, but consider $f(z)=\bar z$.

Comment: Ah, right. Nevermind my previous post.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Does my question makes any sense?

Comment: Define $\sqrt{z}$...

Comment: @trinithis There should be a little ×-shaped button next to your comment that you can use to delete it, if you want to.

Answer (score 6):

$\sqrt z=0\implies \sqrt z\sqrt z=z=0$

Answer (score 2):

As [pointed out in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156357/what-are-the-zeroes-of-sqrtz/156504#comment360641_156357), it depends on how you define $\sqrt{z}$. If one wants it to be analytic on its entire domain of definition, then take a branch of the logarithm and use that to define the square root off the branch cut as $\sqrt{z}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log z}$ (or as -$e^{\frac{1}{2}\log z}$, if you prefer). Now, it isn't difficult to see that as $z\to 0$, then $\sqrt{z}\to 0$ in either case, so we can *continuously* extend our definition of $\sqrt{z}$ to say that $\sqrt{0}=0$, and in that case, can consider $0$ to be the sole zero of $\sqrt{z}$. We just can't *analytically* extend it that way, since $0$ is a branch point (of order $2$) of $\sqrt{z}$.